# error in Xcode - cache derivation lock for key DVTFilePathKey_IsExcludedFromBackup

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

Does anybody have an idea where this error might come from? thanks!

on the Xcode 4.6 worked and when I tried to run it on Xcode 5 it didn't anymore.

```
Process:         Xcode [8878]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [223]
Responsible:     Xcode [8878]
User ID:         503

Date/Time:       2013-12-28 15:48:34.294 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  917EFFFA-D65A-A29A-FA2E-6037CB73CC80

Sleep/Wake UUID: 7ACAF993-17F1-4D95-9532-50E1176C0BBD

Crashed Thread:  5  Dispatch queue: DVTFilePath cache derivation lock for key DVTFilePathKey_IsExcludedFromBackup

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010cae1000-000000010cae2000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```